# Icons in Leaflet tooltips

Tags: leaflet

Trying to add an icon to Leaflet tooltip, but unsuccessfully - does anyone have an example?
For example, adding

```
layer.bindTooltip(msg+"<i class=\"fas fa-headphones\"></i>")
```

doesn't work
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you add to a tooltip can be a html string:

```
layer.bindTooltip("<div><span style='display:block'><strong>Custom Html with an Icon<strong></span><img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/780792637481689088/8y-GChEY.jpg' width='30' /></div>");
```

But I think your problem is that your Font-Awesome style is not working. Have you added the library to your project?